# Error while running function with control statment

Tags: r

I am new to R, the following code I wrote is raising an error:

```
say.true = function(x) {
 if (x == 1) {
   print("hello world")
 } else {
  print("bye world")
 }
}

say.true(1)
```

Comment: I've just undone a bunch of edits to this Q because since the code *does* work when edited, it may be some problem with the way it was entered. Even the `enter code here` line might be the problem, or the way `say.true(1)` is right after a `}` with no new-line. BUT @venkateshpadala has to tell us what the error is and a bit more info.

Comment: @Spacedman  Bunch of edits is my fault.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no error with the above code.

```
say.true = function(x)
{
  if (x ==1)
  {
    print("hello world")
  } else
  {
    print("bye world")
  }

}
say.true(1)
# [1] "hello world"
```